# Unable to install a specific package (bsts / BoomSpikeSlab / Boom) in Google Colab with R

Tags: r

I'm trying to install a R package bsts in Google Colab with R kernel. But I faced some problems.

```
install.packages("bsts")
```

The output is:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

also installing the dependencies ‘BoomSpikeSlab’, ‘zoo’, ‘xts’, ‘Boom’


Warning message in install.packages("bsts"):
“installation of package ‘Boom’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("bsts"):
“installation of package ‘BoomSpikeSlab’ had non-zero exit status”
Warning message in install.packages("bsts"):
“installation of package ‘bsts’ had non-zero exit status”
```

I think the problem is that the R kernel of Google Colab based on Ubuntu. And I have install those dependencies separately, and I find the problems while installing 'BoomSpikeSlab', and 'Boom'.
How can I solve this problem to install the 'bsts' package?

Comment: Hi Yuyang! Welcome to StackOverflow! Does Colab show you any other error messages when trying to install Boom or BoomSpikeSlab?

Comment: Hi Mark. Nothing new. The output is 'Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)'

Answer (score 1):

I've just had an identical issue with identical error messages installing the same packages. I was running R in a Jupyter Notebook on a virtual machine in Google Cloud.

What fixed it in the end was stopping the virtual machine, editing the virtual machine to temporarily increase the memory from 7.5Gb to 15Gb, and then installing Boom again. It seems that Boom in particular needs a lot of memory to install/build.